# Angular routing duplicate windows

Tags: angular

i would like to have some input regarding a routing problem. I am required to display a component two times on the same view. The component will have children components that would need routing, and a children from each component will need to be display at the same time, but never the same view in both of them. The children will have the same routes on both components.
If I explained the requirements right, and you guys understood what I have to do, now comes my question. Should I use router outlet to handle routing in the children components, and if so how should i use it, or should I use the parent components and give each children a value

```
 routeHandler = {
        leftWindow: 'overview',
        rightWindow: 'deal'
    };
```

and then handle it myself. Please let me know if my question does not make sense, and I will be more than happy to clarify things

Comment: the router won't be able to route two different location. You will need to implement router-like feature in the component itself

Comment: @JEY it can route different components in different named outlets, though, which I think is what the OP is describing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh yes forgot about that :)

Comment: even though they are different named outlet they will link to the same components, as it is a duplicate view, which mean we will have something like "/route/right/deal" and "route/left/deal/" which will affect the url structure something that i would not want. will it still work if i am not willing to change the url structure?